# How to move struct only one inside a loop

Tags: rust

I have a simple fifo that has a method `push_back_or_wait`. It tries to `push_back` an element to the fifo in a while loop until it succeeds:

```
while encoded_packets_fifo
    .push_back_or_wait(
        encoded_packet,
        defaults::default_timeout_stoppable
    ).is_none()
    {
        // ...
    }
```

the function:

```
pub fn push_back_or_wait(&mut self, t: T, timeout: Duration) -> Option<()> {
    self.0.push_back_or_wait(t, timeout)
}
```

The problem is that `encoded_packet: EncodedPacket` is a simple struct that is expensive to copy. However I can't send a reference instead of moving `encoded_packet`, because `self.0.push_back_or_wait` requires a move (to store in a fifo, of course).

The problem is that if I try to move it, I get:

```
use of moved value: `encoded_packet`

value moved here, in previous iteration of looprustc(E0382)
bitstream_rtsp_client.rs(91, 25): move occurs because `encoded_packet` has type `common::encoded_packet::EncodedPacket`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

However I clearly only use this once in the iteration, which stops when it successfully sent, so I should be able to *move only once*.

How can I move only once and then stop the iteration?

Comment: You move `encoded_packet` into `push_back_and_wait()` regardless of what it does with it. If you don't push it to the queue, it will be dropped at the end of the function. Either way, it will be gone. One option to solve this problem is by returning the object to the caller in case storing it in the queue fails. You could do that by returning `Result<(), T>` from `push_back_or_wait()`. Inside the loop, you need to handle the error case and assign the returned object back to `encoded_packet`.

Comment: See [`Box::downcast()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.downcast) for a similar pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's expensive to copy it, stop copying it.  Every move is essentially  a copy. Put `Rc<EncodedPacket>` in the fifo instead.

Comment: "Every move is essentially a copy" – this claim is misleading at best. Many moves can be optimised away by the compiler. Additionally, many types are expensive to copy because it's expensive to copy their heap allocations. Cloning a large vector can be expensive. Moving ownership of a large vector is eseentially free.

Comment: Wait, I thought a function call that does not borrow simply moved the value, in the sense that it didn't copy the internal structures. @SvenMarnach, I thought this wasn't even a compiler optimization but instead a behavior of the language. Are there cases when it moves by copying? This has a big impact of my project, I need to know exactly what's happening

Comment: Sven and I both have valid points here.  Sometimes moves are optimized away, sometimes they aren't.  When a rust data structure is moved, only the "top level" of the structure is moved.  When you move a 1000-length`Vec<f64>`, only the 24-byte top level of the `Vec` (essentially `{ ptr: * mut f64, length: usize, used: usize }`) is moved, not the 8000-byte `f64` slice allocation.

Comment: When any `Rc<T>` is cloned, no matter how big the `T` is, the only thing that happens is a reference count is incremented and the top-level pointer is copied.  The "top level" of an `Rc<T>` is just the 8-byte pointer.

Comment: @NovaDenizen nice. Indeed I supposed that for types like Vec, `move` was simply copying the structure. Gonna wrap my Packet inside `Rc` anyways as it could have not easily moveable structures in the future